# Is there a more efficient way of flushing an array in NetMF?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

I have an array over 4000 bytes long, and am currently experiencing performance/speed issues with the following method:

```
public static void FlushThisArray(byte[]Array)
{
    for(int i=0;i<Array.Length;i++)
    {
        Array[i]=0;
    }
}
```

I have also seen the way there is a `.Flush()` Method in NetMF, but seems to also have performance issues?

Anyone know of any better ways of clearing this array?

Comment: Create a new `byte[]` instead of looping and zero-ing it?

Comment: There is limited memory available, and GC doesn't work fast enough (even when forced), as it is for a legacy board (FEZ Panda) :(

Comment: You could try Array.Clear()

Comment: @jbutler483 I think you're underestimating GC.Did you tried that? btw you can use `Array.Clear`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That method (I believe) is unavailable in NETMF.

Comment: Available in the .NET Micro Framework versions 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, and 4.1.

Comment: I'm using 4.1 @MarkO, but there is still no method :(

Comment: Found this issue. I was using the variable 'Array', and so this was not showing up (as it was looking at the variable and not the name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do [`Array.Clear(myArray, 0, myArray.Length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee425396.aspx)

[Edit: Changed link to reference `.NET Micro Framework` documentation.]